# Set value to Static variable from test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, customsetting

A custom setting is being used in a class.

```
public static Map<string,namespace__CustomSetting__c> objCustomSetting  = new Map<string,namespace__CustomSetting__c>() ;

objCustomSetting  = namespace__CustomSetting__c.getAll();
```

How to access these in test Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as unit-tests are run in isolated environment (if seAllData annotation isn't presented), you need to create this custom settings in test first;

```
@testSetup
static void setupCustomSettings(){
    insert new namespace__CustomSetting__c();
}
```

then you can normally access `objCustomSetting`, as it has `public` access modifier.

```
Test.startTest();
    Map<String, namespace__CustomSetting__c> actual = YourClassName.objCustomSetting;
Test.stopTest();
System.assertEquals(1, actual.values(), 'One value should be presented, as one Custom Setting is inserted in testSetup');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the getters and setters for the variable you have used.

```
public static Map<string,namespace__CustomSetting__c> objCustomSetting{get;set;}
```

Getter and setters help you to access the variable outside the class as well. Try the above line instead of your first line of code, and then check.